# How can I vertically align a floated image

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment, horizontal-alignment

When I try to vertically align text on the left to the vertical middle of the image on the right, nothing works.

HTML

`<div class= "div"> <p class= "alignleft">text on the left</p> <img src= "example.jpeg" class= 'alignright'> </div>`

CSS

```
`.div {
align-tiems: center;

}

.alignleft {
  float: left;
}

.alignright {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}`
```

This is what I've got so far. I have no clue how to move further

What I've got

```
              _______
             |       |
```

| text on the left |  | (image right next to it) |
| --- | --- | --- |

What I would like

```
                    ______
                   |      |
```

| text on the left |  | (image on far right) |
| --- | --- | --- |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the way to go here. [howtocenterincss.com](http://howtocenterincss.com/) is a handy online tool to use to give you code to solve most problems. It can be very frustrating aligning text, images and other elements, that's for sure.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* This maximises the space between eleemnts */
  justify-content:space-between;
  
  /* you can use gap if you just want a fixed width between items */
  /* gap: 1rem */
  
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>Some Text here</div>
  <div><img src='https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100'>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit** changed to `justify-content:space-between` as that more closely matches the question meaning.

Comment: I think he wants `justify-content: space-between;` instead of the gap.

Comment: Ok, I'm amend. Thanks for the nudge